# iterating over Object of Objects to perform some logic on values

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, object, time-complexity

Here is my issue:
I have a JSON Object coming in a response from an http request, meaning not all objects inside the jsonResponse will be typeOf string, nor will I know how many objects are found inside the jsonResponse.

```
let jsonResponse = {
    prop1: {
        prop: 'objectKey1'
    },
    prop2: {
        prop2: 'objectKey2',
        num: 2,
        stringy: 'stringy'
    },
    key: 'string',
    anotherKey: 'anotherString',
    prop3: {
        objectKey3: 3,
        objectKey4: 'string',
        prop4: {
            moreKeys: 'string',
            num1: 666
        }
    },
    property: 'anotherString2'
}
```

I want to go over each property/value inside this object, including all of it's child object keys and values in order to check if they are type of string.
if they are a type of string I want to send them to another function to perform a certain logic to that string, and to change it's value inside the jsonResponse.

I tried to do something like this -

```
Object.keys(jsonResponse).forEach((key, indexValue)=>{
    if(typeof(jsonResponse[key])==='string'){
        somelogic(jsonResponse[key])
    } else if (typeof(jsonResponse[key] === 'object')){
        //recurssive function to keep getting keys and values inside the jsonResponse
    }
})
```

It seems that I'm missing some objects inside the jsonResponse because of that, and I don't know how to iterate through the child objects and their respected keys and values.

I know i'm not going through all objects, I'm just unsure how to do it recurssivly or if recurssive is the right way to do it.

I also tried using Object.entries(), but the tricky part for this is that I'll never know how many objects inside the jsonResponse are there, nor will I have any idea how many object of objects are there.

what is the fastest way to do it in manner of time-complexity?

Comment: Why not create a function that does that, and recursively call it. It is basically what you are suggesting. I don't understand what's the problem here.

Comment: I'm asking what is the best way regarding time-complexity? 
Is it recurssive or to flat out the object to arrays of arrays, and creating a new arrays as I go. 
I don't know the number of N, and last I remember N^N is a bit more time consuming than o^N.. 
Again, not 100% in what I say

Answer (score 0):

```js
let jsonResponse = {
  prop1: {
      prop: 'objectKey1'
  },
  prop2: {
      prop2: 'objectKey2',
      num: 2,
      stringy: 'stringy'
  },
  key: 'string',
  anotherKey: 'anotherString',
  prop3: {
      objectKey3: 3,
      objectKey4: 'string',
      prop4: {
          moreKeys: 'string',
          num1: 666
      }
  },
  property: 'anotherString2'
}

function somelogic(a) {
  console.log('>>>', a);
}

function getStringKeys(jsonResponse) {
  Object.keys(jsonResponse).forEach((key, indexValue)=>{
    if(typeof(jsonResponse[key])==='string'){
        somelogic(jsonResponse[key])
    } else if (typeof(jsonResponse[key] === 'object')){
      getStringKeys(jsonResponse[key]);
    }
  })
}

getStringKeys(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Ok, I'm feeling a bit stupid, yes, I was missing that last line and recalling of the funciton. I see what I missed. 
Thank you for your help!